# changing position of labels in mainmenu yii zii.widget.CMenu

Tags: yii

In the default web application created using yii 'Home', 'About' labels are always on left side. How can I change their position or any other label to right end of main menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add class CSS using `htmlOptions` when you create Menu like:

```
//in your view
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
    'id'=>'myMenu',
    'items'=>$this->myMenu,
    'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'right-position'),
));
```

Yii will render like:

```
...
<ul class="right-position" id="myMenu">
...
</ul>
...
```

And You're able to define Css for right-position class like:

```
.right-position
{
  text-align: right;
}
```

So Your Menu-Items should be on the right-side.

**More info:**
If you want apply CSS for each Menu-Item in the different ways, you can use  `itemOptions` and `linkOptions` for this. For example:

```
//At your controller
$this->myMenu = array(
'id'=>'myMenu',
'items'=>array(
    array(
        'label'=>'Home',
        'url'=>array('site/index'),
        'itemOptions'=>array('class'=>'css-item'),
        'linkOptions'=>array('class'=>'css-link'),
    )
),
);
```

Yii will render like:

```
...
<ul id="myMenu">
    <li class="css-item">
        <a class="css-link" href="/site/index">Home</a>
    </li>

...
```

For example: If you want Home item on the right-side the you can define css-item like:

```
.css-item
{
  float: right;
}
```

I hope it's helpful for you.

Comment: thanks for you answer but what will be css-item and css-link. I am new to css stuff.

Comment: I added example in the case you want Home item on the right-side. Please see the css-item style.